# Controlling the VS Debugger per API

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

Is it possible to control the Visual Studio 2019 Debugger for C++ Code with an API?

It would be cool, if the commands like "step over", "step into" to execute and to get the current position in the executed code file.

Like the function which can be used in Visual Studio, but to use them from a custom program.

Comment: What is the reason for this wish? What exactly are you trying to do? A breakpoint can have a condition and an action (writing some text to Output Window).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/using-the-debugger-engine-api

Comment: The link above is not useful for Visual Studio, but for other debuggers (like WinDbg).

Comment: WinDbg can be used to debug VS applications though.

Comment: this could be very useful - you might want to drive a program to a certain state by a programmed series of step into, set variable, step over, set variable, etc etc - or you could want to write a visualizer that aggregated several variables, possibly including a method call (e.g., foo.to_string()) - I can think of other cases as well

Answer (score 2):

You can automate it with my [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) extension and commands like:

```
DTE.ExecuteCommand("Debug.StepOver");
DTE.ExecuteCommand("Debug.StepInto");
```

And get current file, line, method:

```
public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package) 
{
    EnvDTE.TextSelection ts = DTE.ActiveWindow.Selection as EnvDTE.TextSelection;
    if (ts == null)
        return;
    EnvDTE.CodeFunction func = ts.ActivePoint.CodeElement[vsCMElement.vsCMElementFunction]
                as EnvDTE.CodeFunction;
    if (func == null)
        return;
    string result = DTE.ActiveWindow.Document.FullName + System.Environment.NewLine +
      "Line " + ts.CurrentLine + System.Environment.NewLine +
      func.FullName;
    System.Windows.Clipboard.SetText(result);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this could be a possible solution. But it is only a work around, so I will wait to accept the answer.